Crew ai, Local LLM connection issue
I am trying to connect ollama Llama2 with crew ai, and i am getting "openai.NotFoundError: 404 page not found" 
in .env i have below values
OPENAI_API_BASE=http://localhost:11434/v1 OPENAI_MODEL_NAME=llama2 OPENAI_API_KEY=NA
in main file, i have below line to connect
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI

llm = ChatOpenAI(
    model="llama2",
    base_url="http://localhost:11434/v1"
)

i am trying to create a sample crew ai which is connecting with Local LLM,
Note: i installed Local LLM Ollama llama2 succesfully and i can able to run the llm without any issue.
but while connecting with crew ai i am getting error
Below i have detailed error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\crew_ai\crew.py", line 114, in <module>
    result = crew.kickoff()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\crew_ai\.my_crew_env\Lib\site-packages\crewai\crew.py", line 252, in kickoff
    result = self._run_sequential_process()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\crew_ai\.my_crew_env\Lib\site-packages\crewai\crew.py", line 293, in _run_sequential_process
    output = task.execute(context=task_output)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\crew_ai\.my_crew_env\Lib\site-packages\crewai\task.py", line 173, in execute
    result = self._execute(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\crew_ai\.my_crew_env\Lib\site-packages\crewai\task.py", line 182, in _execute
    result = agent.execute_task(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\crew_ai\.my_crew_env\Lib\site-packages\crewai\agent.py", line 207, in execute_task
    memory = contextual_memory.build_context_for_task(task, context)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\crew_ai\.my_crew_env\Lib\site-packages\crewai\memory\contextual\contextual_memory.py", line 22, in build_context_for_task
    context.append(self._fetch_stm_context(query))
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\crew_ai\.my_crew_env\Lib\site-packages\crewai\memory\contextual\contextual_memory.py", line 31, in _fetch_stm_context
    stm_results = self.stm.search(query)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\crew_ai\.my_crew_env\Lib\site-packages\crewai\memory\short_term\short_term_memory.py", line 23, in search
    return self.storage.search(query=query, score_threshold=score_threshold)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\crew_ai\.my_crew_env\Lib\site-packages\crewai\memory\storage\rag_storage.py", line 90, in search
    else self.app.search(query, limit)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\crew_ai\.my_crew_env\Lib\site-packages\embedchain\embedchain.py", line 635, in search
    return [{"context": c[0], "metadata": c[1]} for c in self.db.query(**params)]
                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\crew_ai\.my_crew_env\Lib\site-packages\embedchain\vectordb\chroma.py", line 220, in query
    result = self.collection.query(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\crew_ai\.my_crew_env\Lib\site-packages\chromadb\api\models\Collection.py", line 327, in query
    valid_query_embeddings = self._embed(input=valid_query_texts)
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\crew_ai\.my_crew_env\Lib\site-packages\chromadb\api\models\Collection.py", line 633, in _embed
    return self._embedding_function(input=input)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\crew_ai\.my_crew_env\Lib\site-packages\chromadb\api\types.py", line 193, in __call__
    result = call(self, input)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\crew_ai\.my_crew_env\Lib\site-packages\chromadb\utils\embedding_functions.py", line 188, in __call__
    embeddings = self._client.create(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\crew_ai\.my_crew_env\Lib\site-packages\openai\resources\embeddings.py", line 113, in create
    return self._post(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\crew_ai\.my_crew_env\Lib\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py", line 1232, in post
    return cast(ResponseT, self.request(cast_to, opts, stream=stream, stream_cls=stream_cls))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\crew_ai\.my_crew_env\Lib\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py", line 921, in request
    return self._request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\crew_ai\.my_crew_env\Lib\site-packages\openai\_base_client.py", line 1012, in _request
    raise self._make_status_error_from_response(err.response) from None
openai.NotFoundError: 404 page not found



I believe you are using the memory option(memory=True) in the crewai module for either Crew or Agent object.
CrewAI uses embedchain module for RAG operations and the default provider is set to openai. To use openai embedding model one need to set OPENAI_API_KEY as environment variable. As you have set it to 'NA', it is failing with 404 Page not found error.
One either set the openai key or use another provider for embedding. To set a provider you can refer CrewAI Memory and Embedding models page.
Sample code for using NVIDIA API:
os.environ['NVIDIA_API_KEY'] = 'nvapi-**'
crew = Crew(
  agents=[support_agent, support_quality_assurance_agent],
  tasks=[inquiry_resolution, quality_assurance_review],
  verbose=2,
  memory=True,
  embedder={
          "provider": "nvidia",
          "config": {
            "model": "nvolveqa_40k",
            "vector_dimension": 1024,
          },
    }
)


The official guide from the link works for me.
https://docs.crewai.com/how-to/LLM-Connections/
from langchain.llms import Ollama

llm = Ollama(
    model = "llama2",
    base_url = "http://localhost:11434")

general_agent = Agent(...,
                      llm = llm)


The reason why it is giving the 404 error is because your code is not talking to the Ollama server installed on your machine.
Even though Ollama maybe installed on your machine, you still need to pull a specific model of ollama in order for your code to talk to the server.
You can pull a model of ollama from powershell.
I can see that you are attempting to use llama2. Therefore type "ollama pull lama2" in the powershell

In your tools/crew.py initialize your agents like so:
@agent
def my_dev_agent(self) -> Agent:
    return Agent(
        llm=LLM(
            model="ollama/llama2",
        ),
        config=self.agents_config['my_dev_agent'],
        verbose=True
    )

here ollama/llama2, your local llm, was created like so:
ollama create llama2 -f my_llama2_model

contents of my_llama2_model are like so:
FROM /path/to/local/llama2/model.gguf

